# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSpotLib.default.show')

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting this error while creating a package in react-native iOS side. 
**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSpotLib.default.show')**.

I'm creating this package for a simple alert demo and trying to call on button click and getting this error.

Anyone can help me out of this?

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: So far it looks like this package may not work in expo...in case you're using expo